# I need the Top 10 results from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the Top 10 results for each Region, Market and Name along with those with highest counts (Gaps). There are 4 Regions with 1 to N Markets. I can get the Top 10 but cannot figure out how to do this without using a Union for every Market. Any ideas on how do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
    Region, Market, Name, Gaps 
FROM
    TableName
ORDER BY 
    Region, Market, Gaps DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) if you're on SQL Server 2005 and newer (you aren't specific enough in that regard).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `Region, Market, Name` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by some criteria.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH RegionsMarkets AS
(
   SELECT 
       Region, Market, Name, Gaps,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Region, Market, Name ORDER BY Gaps DESC) 
   FROM 
       dbo.TableName
)
SELECT 
   Region, Market, Name, Gaps
FROM 
   RegionsMarkets
WHERE
   RN <= 10
```

Here, I am selecting only the "first" entry for each "partition" (i.e. for each `Region, Market, Name` tuple) - ordered by `Gaps` in a descending fashion.

With this, you get the top 10 rows for each (`Region, Market, Name`) tuple - does that approach what you're looking for??

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by region, market order by gaps desc) as seqnum
      from tablename t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

I am not sure if you want `name` in the `partition by` clause.  If you have more than one name within a market, that may be what you are looking for.  (Hint: Sample data and desired results can really help clarify a question.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked exactly with what i got using a lot of Unions joined together.